# How to deduce the return type of a function template base on a "function like" parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following function template:

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename Op>
B Apply(A a, Op f)
{
    return f(a);
}
```

To use it, one has to explicitly specify the template parameters:

```
auto y = Apply<int, std::string>(2, [](int x){ return std::to_string(x); });
```

I would like to create a version where the parameters are deduced by the compiler, such
that I can call it as `auto y = Apply(...);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) cookbook solution for applying a functor:

1. Use forwarding references.
2. `std::forward` the living daylights out of everything.
3. `decltype(auto)` for the return type

Which we can use to simmer your code sample into this:

```
template<typename F, typename A>
decltype(auto) Apply(F&& f, A&& a) {
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<A>(a));
}
```

For extra seasoning, we can also supply an exception specification:

```
template<typename F, typename A>
decltype(auto) Apply(F&& f, A&& a) 
  noexcept(noexcept(std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<A>(a)))) {
  return std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<A>(a));
}
```

Comment: I understand why you use `F&&` and `A&&`; but I cannot see why you use `std::forward` in this situation. They are redundant. What is the difference between `return f(A)` and your version?

Comment: @ArdaAytekin - `operator()` for a general functor is a member function. It can be overloaded on a ref qualifier (`operator()(...) &&` and `operator()(...) &`). And naturally the parameters can be of various reference types. We want to preserve the value category of the functor and the arguments to call the correct overload. Hence we forward everything.

Comment: one final question. your use of `noexcept` seems a bit different to me, too. according to [`noexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept_spec), does it not need to evaluate to a `bool`? what am I missing this time, could you hint again?

Comment: @ArdaAytekin - That's just C++ being "charming". The outer noexcept is   the specifier you linked to. The inner one, is the [`noexcept` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept). The operator determines if the expression is potentially throwing, and yields the `bool` we then feed to the specifier.

Comment: @ArdaAytekin - And it's horrible if you ask me. I've seen production quality libraries that resort to `#define NOEXCEPT(...) noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__))` to get around this mess. I just present it without embellishments in this answer.